# Why does my nested loop append only the last thing in python?

Tags: python

I am working on a simple math problem that requires me to find a list of Sval values per k per w value. I have this nested for loops.

```
w = [0,1/3,-1]
k = [0,-1]
S = 0.001

Sval = [S]*30
Sval_list = []

for wval in w:
    for kval in k:
        
        for i in range(1, 30):
            Sval[i] = Sval[i-1]+wval-kval
 
        print("{},{}".format(wval,kval),Sval)
        Sval_list.append(Sval)
```

The loops is expected to loop for six times, each loop would output a list of Sval. I expected an outcome of a list with shape(6,30), which I got. But it is appending the output list from 6th loop for six times, instead of appending one output list per loop. Any help to solve this question or to make my codes neater is welcomed!

Comment: can you simplify your code with the part you have the issue? (not dealing with numbers and math)

Comment: @No.BoD Simplified! Please help take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the program, `Sval_list` contains six copies of `Sval` (a list), since you appended it 6 times. Each time you run through the inner most `for` loop and modify `Sval`, it modifies all copies of `Sval` in `Sval_list` since that's how lists work in python, and that's why all lists in `Sval_list` are the same at the end.

You can fix this by effectively detaching each `Sval` when you append it to `Sval_list`. Instead of writing `Sval_list.append(Sval)`, write `Sval_list.append(list(Sval))`. The `list` will create a new list that no longer changes when you change `Sval`.

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is in using the reference, by appending the `Sval` reference to the `Sval_list`.
you get a shallow copy of `Sval` as value and with change of `Sval`, all your data would be changed. appending a hard copy of `Sval` to the `Sval_list` would do the job:

```py
Sval_list.append(Sval[:])
```